# RegQueryValueExW returns Access violation reading location exception in C

Tags: c, windows, registry, access-violation

I have two functions written in C that are supposed to read some information from the Windows registry. Although both use the same logic, one of them throws an error.
The functions that works gets some CPU info.

```
struct CPUInfo {
    wchar_t model[128];
    DWORD frequency;
};

struct CPUInfo cpuinfo() {
    SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
    HKEY hKey;

    struct CPUInfo cpu = { L"", 0 };

    LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0",
        0,
        KEY_READ,
        &hKey
    );
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(cpu.model);

        ULONG nError = RegQueryValueExW(
            hKey,
            L"ProcessorNameString",
            0,
            NULL,
            (LPBYTE)cpu.model,
            &dwBufferSize
        );
        dwBufferSize = sizeof(DWORD);
        nError = RegQueryValueExW(
            hKey,
            L"~MHz",
            0,
            NULL,
            (LPBYTE)(&cpu.frequency),
            &dwBufferSize
        );
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return cpu;
}
```

This functios works and the information is retrieved from the registry. Now, I do the same a second time with this function

```
struct GPUInfo {
    DWORD adaptersCount;
};

struct GPUInfo gpuinfo() {
    HKEY hKey;
    struct GPUInfo gpu = { 0 };

    LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\VIDEO",
        0,
        KEY_READ,
        &hKey
    );
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(DWORD);
        ULONG nError = RegQueryValueExW(
            hKey,
            L"MaxObjectNumber",
            0,
            NULL,
            (LPBYTE)(&gpu.adaptersCount),
            dwBufferSize
        );

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    return gpu;
}
```

When I debug the program, like I said, the first function works but the second one throws an exception at this point:

```
ULONG nError = RegQueryValueExW( // !!!! Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000004
    hKey,
    L"MaxObjectNumber",
    0,
    NULL,
    (LPBYTE)(&gpu.adaptersCount),
    dwBufferSize
);
```

I have checked in the registry and the path does exist. Really do not understand why the first one works but the second one doesn't. I call them on after another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your compiler warnings. You're passing `lpcbData` (the buffer length) *by value* and not *by address*.

It should look like this:

```
DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(gpu.adaptersCount);  // (2)
ULONG nError = RegQueryValueExW(
        hKey,
        L"MaxObjectNumber",
        0,
        NULL,
        (LPBYTE)(&gpu.adaptersCount),
        &dwBufferSize                // (1)
    );
```

Changes:

1. Add ampersand in front of `dwBufferSize`, just like your first example
2. Use `sizeof` your actual structure member. This is equivalent, but safer in face of future changes.

Reference:
- [`RegQueryValueExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexw)

Comment: Man, I'm getting old. My mistake, not using a proper IDE that shows me the problem before compiling. Thanks